# Servicestack - possibility of mapping several POCO to one table

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm looking for a way to map several POCO objects into single table in the ServiceStack.

Is it possible to do this in a clean way, without "hacking" table creation process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, [In OrmLite: 1 Class = 1 Table](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#fast-simple-typed-orm-for-net).

But I'm not clear what you mean my "map several POCO objects into single table", it sounds like using [Auto Mapping](http://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping) to populate a table with multiple POCO instances, e.g:

```
var row = db.SingleById<Table>(id);
row.PopulateWithNonDefaultValues(instance1);
row.PopulateWithNonDefaultValues(instance2);
db.Update(row);
```

If you need to maintain a single table and have other "sub" classes that maintain different table in the universal table you can use `[Alias]` so all Update/Select/Insert's reference the same table, e.g:

```
public class Poco
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

[Alias(nameof(Poco))]
public class PocoName
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Alias(nameof(Poco))]
public class PocoAge
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Although I don't really see the benefit over having a single table that you use AutoMapping to map your other classes to before using that in OrmLite.

Comment: ok, this sounds sensible

But the problem is to create the table first out of different classes

Comment: I'd need one huge class that contains all the properties + several smaller dtos for updating parts of the table.

Comment: @A.D. I've updated my answer with an Alias example, but I don't see why you can't just use Auto Mapping to map your DTOs back to the single Data Model class.

Comment: @A.D. You'd have the unified class containing all the properties and only create it once. The other classes with aliases are essentially "Views" of the larger target class.